# Combining two sentences into a single one for a title

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english

I would like to combine two sentences that describe two distinct applications of a tool into a single sentence. This sentence will be used as a title. A reader should be albe to take out of the title that this tool has two applications which refer to a system.

Here are the sentences:

1. This is a tool for assisting engineers in the process of building up a system.
2. This is a tool for assessing automatically the quality of a system.

Combination: This is a tool for assisting traffic engineers in the process of building up and automatically assessing the quality of a system.

1. Is it clear from the sentence above that the first application is "assisting engineers in the process of building up a system", and the second is "automatic assessment of the quality of a system"?
2. If "build up" and "assess the quality **of**" refer to the same noun, can they be combined as above?

Comment: No. << This is a tool for assisting engineers in the process of building up a system[,] and
 for assessing automatically the quality of a system. >> works. In your suggested version, [process of building up and automatically assessing ...] is mandated.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is there a way to omit the repetition of the word system here? Is the following sentence correct?
"This is a tool for assisting engineers in the process of building up a system[,] and for assessing automatically its quality."

Comment: "This is a tool to assist engineers in the design and maintenance of traffic control systems." For a title, you do not need too much detail. That can be expounded in the text that follows.

Comment: Ok, what about a shorter version of the original one that does mention these two applications: "this is a tool to assist engineers in building a system and for automatically assessing its quality"?